# How can the amount of files in blobstorage be reduced?

Tags: plone, blobstorage

I've a Plone site with a blobstorage of 95000 files.
With some days of backup the total amount of files exceeds the limit of the virtual server.

Comment: @bdares: not entirely; unless your hard drive holds onto file revisions ad infinitum until cleaned, in any case. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

- Pack your ZODB if you haven't already. Removing old transaction data will also result in the BLOB files for those transactions being removed.

  Of course, packing removes history, so if you need to be able to undo transactions you may want to only pack until 30 days ago or similar.
- Use a dedicated ZEO server with higher virtual server file limits to store your ZODB and the blobstorage, then use a blob cache on the client(s).

  Use a non-shared blobstorage; your Zope servers will pull in BLOBs over the network from the ZEO server to be stored in the local blob cache, which can be limited in total disk space. (A shared blobstorage is a directory shared over NAS or something similar defeating the purpose here).

  This does not lower the number of BLOB files to back up but perhaps makes it more manageable for you as the ZEO server can be spec-ed for disk space instead of CPU and memory load. The blob caches on the client machines need not be backed up at all.
- Re-tool your application to not have so many BLOBs or to not alter them so often. Ultimately, that's where all your blob files come from; the ZODB uses one blob file per ZODB blob per transaction that alters them.

Comment: AFAIR, packing the blob storage will only truncate the blobs to 0 bytes, but not remove them.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: No, packing definitely removes files (`os.remove` is called on the files); I just verified this. Also, directories are removed when empty.